# gtsummary p value factor levels

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am creating a tbl_summary and adding a p-value for comparison beteween groups. Is there away to add p-value for comparison of factor levels between groups? i.e p-value for Grade I (35 vs 33), Grade II (32 vs 36) and Grade III (21 vs 43) and not just getting an overall p 0.080.

Standard table with `add_p()`

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr) 
    trial %>% 
      select(death,grade) %>% 
      tbl_summary(by = death) %>% 
      add_p() # can something be added to this call for p-compairsons?
```

This is the result I would like but is there a built in method to `add_p()` to get this result for many variables?

```
 trial %>% 
  select(death,grade) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(grade,grade) %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("(I)"), ~ ifelse(is.na(.),0,1))) %>%
  select(-rn) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = death) %>% 
  add_p()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to modify `add_p()` to add the p-values you're requesting. You could do it with a custom function using `add_stat()`, or the way you've done above is also great.

I modified your code slightly to add a label row for the grade levels, and indented the levels.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- 
  trial %>% 
  select(death,grade) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(grade,grade) %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("(I)"), ~ ifelse(is.na(.),0,1))) %>%
  select(-rn) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = death) %>% 
  add_p() %>%
  # add header row for grade, and indenting levels
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      mutate(
        row_type = "level",
        variable = "grade"
      ) %>%
      {bind_rows(tibble(variable = "grade", row_type = "label", label = "Grade"), .)}
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into add_stat()